# Complex flex menu in responsive design

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

I'm trying to make a menu responsive menu which will change orientation with the page marge, smoothly if it's possible (it would be perfect if I can use some css translation to animate it) [image: icon changing orientation]

The icons should fill the marge but not impinge on the text.

I have currently made this with inline-block, margin and `@media only screen and (max-width:XXX)`  but it's not smooth at all
I want to know if there is a better way to do that, with flex box maybe? I'm not as good as I want to in advenced css, so if you have some clue or advice to how to do that, I would be grateful.

The html is basic :

```
<aside id="menu-right">
        <div class="icon-float icon-white">
            <a href="#top" title="Up">Up</a>
        </div>
        <div class="icon-float">
            <a href="#" title="Home">Home</a>
        </div>
        <div class="icon-float">
            <a href="#" title="Search">Search</a>
        </div>
        <div class="icon-float">
            <a href="#" title="Down">Down</a>
        </div>
</aside>
```

My css is pretty ugly so... retart from penuts seems to be a good idea...

Thanks for your reading!

Answer (score 0):

```css
#menu-right {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap-reverse;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-content: flex-end;
}

.icon-float {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<aside id="menu-right">
  <div class="icon-float icon-white">
    <a href="#top" title="Up">4</a>
  </div>
  <div class="icon-float">
    <a href="#" title="Home">3 </a>
  </div>
  <div class="icon-float">
    <a href="#" title="Search">2 </a>
  </div>
  <div class="icon-float">
    <a href="#" title="Down">1</a>
  </div>
</aside>
```

Comment: It's close but actually it's the reversed result. On the bottom when the marge is large enough, on the right when it's not the case.

Comment: Okey! Seems good! 
Do you have an idea how to avoid this case? http://puu.sh/CgUp7/1290558bc4.png

Comment: What in that pic specifically do you need to avoid?

Comment: I want it to be one of this two way 
http://puu.sh/CgUsq/06d11fb289.png Does it seem to be possible?